# AngularJS - $rootScope.currentUser not being transferred from profile page to settings page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, authentication, get

I have a site with Angular/Express/Node/Passport that I am trying to put together. I am setting up angular to watch the `$rootScope.currentUser` variable, here is some code:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    //watching the value of the currentUser variable.
    $rootScope.$watch('currentUser', function(currentUser) {
      // if no currentUser and on a page that requires authorization then try to update it
      // will trigger 401s if user does not have a valid session
      if (!currentUser && (['/', '/login', '/logout', '/signup'].indexOf($location.path()) == -1 )) {
        Auth.currentUser();
      }
    });

    // On catching 401 errors, redirect to the login page.
    $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {
      //console.log(currentUser);
      $location.path('/login');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Using console messages, I have established that the `$rootScope.currentUser` is not available when I go from the profile page (after login) to the settings page (where you can change your password) - because when the `currentUser` is watched (above) - it does the `Auth.currentUser()` function - and gets rejected because `$rootScope.currentUser` is null.

Here is some more, possibly relevant, code:

Auth.js (where `Auth.currentUser()` is)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('groundup')
  .factory('Auth', function Auth($location, $rootScope, Session, User, $cookieStore) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = $cookieStore.get('user') || null;
    $cookieStore.remove('user');
    $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn;

    return {

      login: function(provider, user, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        //console.log(user);
        Session.save({
          //provider: provider,
          username: user.username,
          password: user.password,
          //rememberMe: user.rememberMe
        }, function(user) {
          console.log(user);
          $rootScope.currentUser = user;
          $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn = true;
          console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
          $location.path('/profile');
          return cb();
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return cb(err.data);
        });
      },

      logout: function(callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        Session.delete(function(res) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = null;
            $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn = false;
            console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
            return cb();
          },
          function(err) {
            return cb(err.data);
          });
      },

      createUser: function(userinfo, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        console.log(userinfo);
        User.save(userinfo,
          function(user) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = user;
            $rootScope.currentUserSignedIn = true;
            console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
            $location.path('/profile');
            return cb();
          }
        );
      },

      currentUser: function() {
        Session.get(function(user) {
          console.log(user);
          $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        });
      },

      changePassword: function(oldPassword, newPassword, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;

        return User.update({
          oldPassword: oldPassword,
          newPassword: newPassword
        }, function(user) {
          return cb(user);
          $location.path('/');
        }, function(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }).$promise;
      },

      removeUser: function(email, password, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        User.delete({
          email: email,
          password: password
        }, function(user) {
            console.log(user + 'removed');
            return cb();
        }, function(err) {
            return cb(err.data);
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

After `Auth.currentUser()` it does a get request, which executes this function from the express side:

```
exports.session = function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.user.user_info + " in session function");
  res.json(req.user.user_info);
};
```

The problem is on the redirect to the `/settings` page - because `$rootScope.currentUser` is being watched, it auto redirects to `/login` because the `Auth.currentUser()` fails somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks (look at how $cookieStore is being used in Auth.js - I am not exactly sure how that is working).

Answer (score 1):

There is something strange with your `Auth.currentUser()`, try to change it into something like this to use the `User` service

```
currentUser: function () {
    return User.get();
}
```

Your problem might also comes from a cookie storage problem, Passport tries to save the current user in it but fails somewhere (cause of trying access an undefined var or something) and stores in the cookie a corrupted / empty user.
So the first page is loaded correctly, but when your app tries to access the cookie, it breaks.

I also advice you to look into the `middleware.js` file in the lib directory to see if there is no problem with the cookie saving, like if you want to get all the user object into it instead of just `userInfo`. In this case you will have to modify a little your `session` function to output the entire user.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help - i think you pushed me in the right direction - I should be using the User resource instead of the Session resource to get the user info - the thing is - the user info should already be in the session...so what I am doing should work...

Comment: If something bad is saved when requesting the session resource, that may cause your problem

Comment: there arent any bad requests - everything goes through normally

Comment: I still havent fixed it, although i think i made some positive changes to my code - im still not sure what is wrong...I changed my Auth.currentUser to this...`currentUser: function() {
        Session.get()
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
      },`

Comment: do you have time to chat?